# looping matrix ordo 4X4

Tags: c++

i have problem with code,where i can't looping data in c++.
so here my code:

```
int j,i;

int matriks[5][5];

for(i=0; i<5; i++)
{    
    for(j=0; j<5; j++)
        matriks[i][j]=j;
}
for(i=1; i<5; i++)
{
    for(j=1; j<5; j++)
        cout<<matriks[i][j]<<" ";
    cout<<endl;
    getch();
}
```

the code above only shows

```
1 2 3 4
```

i want output like this:

```
1 2  3  4

5 6  7  8

9 10 11 12

13 14 15 16
```

where is wrong code,how to create looping matrix ordo 4x4?

Comment: Could you have another go at formatting the code (to make it readable)

Comment: The program waits for you to press a key. Isn't that why you put `getch()` inside the loop? Further, you never assign any value greater than `4` to any element of `matriks`, so it's not clear how you expect `5` to be printed.

Comment: place body of the loops inside `{ .. }`

Comment: @George [When you "fixed formatting", it looks like you also *added* curly braces to the code](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14652177). Please don't do that when you are editing code in questions. That could have been the person's problem, so your fixing "typos" in the code just makes the question confusing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code; I did not compile or test, but it looks like what you are trying to achieve.

```
    int matrix[5][5];
    for (int i = 0, k = 0; i < 5; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            matrix[i][j] = k++;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";
        }

        cout << endl;
    }
```